# How to convert string into datetime format c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to convert string 201702070001 into DateTime format like 2017-02-07 00:01

For this I tried like as below. I also followed the tutorial http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/. but not able to solve the problem.

```
string dateTime = "201702070001";
IFormatProvider culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US", true);
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Parse(dateTime, culture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
```

Comment: DateTime does not have any format. What your code is trying to do is *parsing* the string with your desired output format. Which it doesn't comply to.

Comment: Does the format `"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"` look *anything* like your input string?

Comment: To add to Amy's comment, your input string doesn't have spaces, colons, or slashes. That should be a clue.

Comment: "201702070001" and "20170302254" are not in the same format. First one could be "HH" or "hh" for hour, second one probably is "h".

Comment: 20170302254 is not a valid date..

Comment: @DragandDrop It's March, 2nd 2017 2:54 ... How is that not valid?

Comment: Please do not down vote the question

Comment: You can `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhmm");` It work so it is valid, right? 
But the output is not a datetime anymore.. if your time is past 10.. you just loose a valuable information that make it a datetime.

Comment: @Bheesham the best way to avoid downvotes is to write a good question with valid code.

Answer (score 3):

You have to convert it using the right format. Like this:

```
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.ParseExact("201702070001", "yyyyMMddHHmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: "20170302254" gets me thinking it could be "yyyyMMddhmm"

Comment: thanks its working for me

Answer (score 1):

You should first convert the string into `DateTime` object and then using the custom date formatting strings to print the `DateTime`, based on your needs.

Below is an example

```
var dateStr = "201702070001";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateStr, "yyyyMMddHHmm", null);
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"));
```

I am using the default `FormatProvider`. Depending on the locale settings on your computer, it might or might not work for you

You have provided 2 examples: `201702070001` and `20170302254`. They are not consistent with each other. The first one fits `yyyyMMddHHmm` but the other does not. You will have to find the proper format string that you need. You can reference the correct format specifiers from [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)